# Sign Modulator - Class Project

Tags: 555, modulator

I need to simulate a specific circuit, and I'm running out of time, so please someone can tell me what I am doing wrong?

[image]

1. I think I have this part correct:
   [image]
   [image]
2. Here starts the problems, I don't know how to acquire the form of Vramp.

[image]

[image]

As I don't have finish, I don't have Vcr so I put a function generator with a square signal, 5 kHz, duty cycle 50%, amplitude Vp = 6 and offset = 6 V.

3. Then, the output of each part go to a comparator, and the output goes to a 555.

[image]
[image]

The 555 output it the final part and it is the Vcr to the second part.

This is the complete circuit:

[image]

If someone can help me, thank you!

Comment: Don't you need a resistor pullup at the output of the comparator LM311 ? Don' you need that pin EMIT OUT get wired to ground ? https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm311.pdf?ts=1701161020516&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252Fde-de%252FLM311

Comment: @Antonio51, thank you very much, I followed your advice and implemented a pull-up resistor at the output of the LM311, and connected the "EMIT OUT" pin to ground.

However, I'm still experiencing issues with the response of the 555 timer in my circuit. Despite making these changes, the timer doesn't seem to be generating the expected pulse.

I've carefully reviewed the circuit diagram and component values, but I'm still unable to get the timer to respond correctly. 

Best regards,

Comment: Cute, a zener diode bootstrapping a resistor; have you verified that the LM741 is performing this function accurately, though? Pay particular attention to input common mode voltage range and supply voltages.

Answer (score 0):

- The output of the LM311 must be wired to Vcc through a pullup resistor of 2 kΩ.
- The EMIT OUT pin must be wired to ground.

Two pins of the timer 555 must be wired:

- RST (pin 4 to VCC) and ...
- CONT (pin 5 to a 10 nF capacitor wired at ground).

https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/555_timer.html

The output (or inverse ?) of the LM555 should be wired to the input of your R5.
You don't need the XFG1 generator.

If you want, you should modify circuit as here it is.

[image]

[image]

Curves are more linear.

Don't you need something like this, paragraph 4, figures 9 and 10. https://antrak.org.tr/images/stories/pic_2010/mayis/555/LM555.pdf

Her is another circuit.

[image]